# Using RabbitMQ fields in Logstash output

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash

I want to use some fields from RabbitMQ messages into Logstah Elasticsearch output (like a index name, etc).

If I use `[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][timestamp]` in filter it works nice, but not in output statement (config below).

What am I doing wrong?

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "rabbitmq:5672"
        user => "user"
        password => "password"
        queue => "queue "
        durable => true
        prefetch_count => 1
        threads => 3
        ack => true
        metadata_enabled => true
    }
}

filter {
  if [@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][timestamp] {
    date {
      match => ["[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][timestamp]", "UNIX"]
    }
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['http://elasticsearch:9200']
        index => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][IndexName]}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }

    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Comment: The question you've asked already has an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577665/logstash-sprintf-formatting-for-elasticsearch-output-plugin-not-working), that's why I flagged it as possible duplicate. As explained in the answer to the linked question, you have to add the `manage_template => false` option for your elasticsearch output for it to behave as you intended.

Answer (score -1):

check with replace function as mentioned below.

```
input {
        rabbitmq {
            host => "rabbitmq:5672"
            user => "user"
            password => "password"
            queue => "queue "
            durable => true
            prefetch_count => 1
            threads => 3
            ack => true
            metadata_enabled => true
        }
    }

    filter {
      if [@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][timestamp] {
        date {
          match => ["[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][timestamp]", "UNIX"]
        }
      }
      mutate {
        replace => {
          "[@metadata][index]" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][IndexName]}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
      }
    }

    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ['http://elasticsearch:9200']
            index => "%{[@metadata][index]}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }

        stdout {codec => rubydebug}
    }
```