# How to create a custom named time based indexing using logstash?

Tags: indexing, logstash, elastic-stack

Currently i am trying to create a time based indexing in an Elastic search using Logstash. I am trying to create a time based indexing.

I have come across and successfully tried the following output mechanism in Logstash config file.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]

    index => "logstash-%{+xxxx.ww}"
}
file{path=>"C:/output3.txt"}
}
```

This is working fine But the name is required to be "logstash".
I need to give it some custom name other than logstash.
Can you please suggest something.
Thanks again

Comment: Use the `manage_template => false` option in the elasticsearch output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logstash sprintf formatting for elasticsearch output plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577665/logstash-sprintf-formatting-for-elasticsearch-output-plugin-not-working)