# Why does the Logstash ignore my configurations for filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm using the Logstash version 6.7. There is my logstash.config content:

```
input{
    beats{
        port => "5044"
    }
}

filter {

    if "logFromRemote" in [tags] {
        xml {
            source => "message"
            store_xml => "false"

            xpath => ["/LogEntry/ID/text()", "id"]
            xpath => ["/LogEntry/Timestamp/text()", "timestamp"]
            xpath => ["/LogEntry/LogLevel/text()", "logLevel"]
            xpath => ["/LogEntry/Message/text()", "msg"]
            xpath => ["/LogEntry/Exception/text()", "exception"]

        }
    }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

The logstash successfully receives messages from my filebeat, but it ignores my configuration. The XML parser does not work and all data go to the filebeat-{date} index, instead in filebeat-{version}-{date} like I have described in the config.

There is also file "beats.config". I tried to put same configurations there, but without success.

Comment: I think it's because the elasticsearch is missing the manage_template => false option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596805/6113627

Comment: can you share your filebeat config as well?

Comment: The problem is that Logstash totaly ignores the configuration file. Logstash runs on my machine as a windows service. If I start it and run it manually, running this command " ./logstash -f logstash.config", it works perfectly. Index name is correct and there are all fields that I defined in the filter section, so I think my filebeat is configured well.

Comment: @AleksandarMuchi How did you configure logstach to run as windows service

Comment: I installed the Logstash using the NSSM, and at that moment I defined argument "-f Logstash\bin\logstash.json", so the service uses this file. I put my configuration in this file and now it works perfectly. Thank you for your question, it navigated me to the right direction :)